# Adding values to fixed array of strings only appends to the first element of the array

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to create a function that returns an array of strings. Sadly instead of returning an array that has N number of elements of type string, it just appends all my string values to the first and only element in the array.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Store is Ownable {
    struct Product {
        string name;
        uint32 quantity;
        bool exists;
    }

    uint64 private productId;

    mapping(uint => Product) private products;

    constructor() {
        productId = 1;
    }

    function addProduct(string calldata name, uint32 quantity) public onlyOwner
        require(quantity > 0, "Quantity cannot be negative integer");

        productId = productId + 1;

        products[productId] = Product(name, quantity, true);
    }

    function listProducts() external view returns (string[] memory){
        string[] memory productsInfo = new string[](productId);

        if(productId < 1){
            return productsInfo;
        }

        for(uint i = 0; i < productId; i++){
            string memory info = products[i + 1].name;

            productsInfo[i] = info;
        }

        return productsInfo;
    }
}
```

If I add products a, b, c. The json result from colling `listProducts()` looks like this:

```
{
    "0": "string[]: a,b,c"
}
```

Comment: can you pls show how you implemented `addProduct` function?

Comment: I have updated the post, to show also the `addProduct` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the contract is working.
Solidity display the elements in array with commas between them.
Array return start with "0" string[].

Hope it will help

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Store{
    struct Product {
        string name;
        uint32 quantity;
        bool exists;
    }
     address private Owner; 
     uint64 private productId;
     mapping(uint => Product) private products;

     constructor() {
        productId = 1;
        Owner = msg.sender;
     }

     modifier onlyOwner{
        require(msg.sender == Owner, "Fail! only admin can access this 
        function!");
         _;
      }

    function addProduct(string calldata _name, uint32 _quantity) public 
    onlyOwner{
        Product memory _strucObj;
        _strucObj.name = _name;
        _strucObj.quantity = _quantity;
        products[productId -1] = _strucObj;
        productId++;
    }

    function listProducts() external view returns (string[] memory){
        string[] memory productsInfo = new string[](productId);

        if(productId < 1){
            return productsInfo;
        }

        //dash symbol used for concatenation
        string memory dash = "-";

        for(uint i = 0; i < productId; i++){
            string memory info = products[i].name;

            productsInfo[i] = info;
        }

        return productsInfo;
    }

   function CheckProductsByIndex(uint index) public view returns(string memory name)
    {
         string[] memory productsInfo = new string[](productId);
         for(uint i = 0; i < productId; i++)
         {
             string memory _toArray = products[i].name;
             productsInfo[i] = _toArray;
         }
        return productsInfo[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made the `products mapping` public so that it created getter automatically, and also added your function and everything is good . There is indeed couple of elements in the mapping, but the `listProducts` function returns array with 1 element, which has all the names of the products concatenated in that one array element.

Comment: is there commas between the elements?

Comment: you know you need to call your addproduct for each product sepretly right? on each call you create one element. you can check that the values are in different element of the array by calling the array by index and see the result, i checked it again and it is working.

Comment: Yes there is commas between the elements. The return looks like this in remix `"0": "string[]: Ivan,aaa,bbb,ccc"`, also yes I am adding the products 1 by 1 with the `addproduct` function.

Comment: this is an array, each commas separate elements, you can check its true by calling the array by index. so your result return an array with 4 elements "Ivan", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc".

Comment: is this not the result you want?

Comment: Ohh I expected the result to be `"0": "string[]: aaa` `"1": "string[]: bbb` `"2": "string[]: ccc`

Comment: I see! No problem then, your contract work. if you do want to get single element use index. If my help was good pls mark answer as good! Good luck brother.

Comment: can you add in your answer, that the contract is working, and that solidity display the elements in array in an index `0`